how does a row or column of 0s affect if a matrix is defective?
Say $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
If I want to find out if $A$ is defective does the row of 0's or column of 0's give me any clue? Is there a theorem on this?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

This is in the Jordan normal form already. I'm inclined to believe that this matrix is defective.

The accepted answer seems to be what you're looking for, but to answer the question in your title, a row of zeros has very little bearing on whether a matrix is defective or not. It implies (but is not equivalent to) the matrix having an eigenvalue of $0$. Whether the Jordan block(s) containing $0$ are $1 \times 1$, or whether the other Jordan blocks are $1 \times 1$, cannot be read from the matrix more quickly than normal, just because the matrix has a $0$ row.

@TheoBendit Yeah I kind of gathered that from the accepted answer but I appreciate the clarification. If I understand correctly, It's not that the row or column is all zeros but that the eigenvalue will result in zero. There could be values other than zero in some places like (5,4) that still result in eigenvalue 0. Conversely, there could be a full row or column of zeros that could yield a nonzero eigenvalue, if the other values are populated with nonzero values

@CodingNinja I may not have understood you correctly, but that seems right. None of any of this has any bearing on whether the matrix is defective or not (except if the matrix has all $0$s, in which case it is the zero matrix, and is not defective).

The matrix $A$ is clearly defective. This is because, it is in its Jordan form with only two Jordan blocks, as opposed to $5$ different blocks for diagnolizability. It is not row or column of zeros but the number of blocks in the Jordan form or, equivalently the number of distinct factors of minimal polynomial of the matrix that matters for a matrix to be defective.
